# Multispectral camera

Tags: pi-3, camera

I would like to use a NoIr camera and an rgb camera in order to do calculations with the near-ir band and the RGB bands. Is there a way I can get near-ir values from the NoIr camera?

Comment: use calibrated filters

Comment: Can I just use the red values as the Near-IR I have seen they near -ir transmittance is above 80% and red is below 15%

Comment: it is unclear why you are asking instead of testing ... btw, your question is not specific to the Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of doing this is to put an optical filter in front of the lens, that blocks out all wavelengths except those you require. However, if you can calibrate the two cameras enough that they actually show the same image, you can subtract the R channel of the IR-filtered RGB camera from the R channel of the NoIr camera to get a pseudo-IR channel. But for the best results, optical filtering (with the associated light loss) will be necessary.